# Blog platform that has built in syntax highlighting

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs, blogger

I want to start writing some blog and I know that i will past code there so i am looking for some platform with this already built in . And that i will not need to use third party script  for syntax highlighting.

As I understood Blogger and Word press   dont have that built in and they use syntax [highlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/w/list) .

The problem is that i am really not understand in web programming and I am not sure to install all those scripts .

Thanks .

Comment: If you're not a programmer, what are you doing on this site? Why are you writing a blog that requires syntax highlighting?

Comment: I am a desktop application programmer and not web programmer

Comment: You shouldn't look for built-in syntax highlighting. [Prism](http://prismjs.com/) is incredibly easy to integrate in any site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress is designed so that all you ever have to do is write - i.e. you don't have to be a web developer to use the platform while you're blogging.  You add functionality through plug-ins, which are optional modules you download, install, activate, and configure *within the WordPress GUI*.  No coding skills required.

#### Getting WordPress

You can get a free WordPress blog at [WordPress.com](http://www.wordpress.com).  You might also be able to set one up on your own domain through your web host with a one-click-installation tool (this depends on your host).  Finally, you can usually find a developer who will install WordPress on your hosted server for free ([Here's an example](http://tddewey.com/pricing) of an Arizona developer who offers free WordPress installation.)

To install a syntax highlighter, you'll need to be running WordPress on your own server.  The free WordPress.com setup doesn't allow you to install additional plug-ins.  But setting up WordPress on your own server is fast, relatively easy, and as I mentioned before, very well supported by the community.

#### Installing a Plug-in

You can search for plug-ins and install them *directly within the WordPress dashboard.*  Just go to your dashboard, click **Plugins** then click on the big **Add New** button at the top of the page.  From this screen, you can browse available plug-ins by tag or search for a specific feature.

Once you've found a plug-in you like, click **Install Now** and follow the on-screen instructions to install and activate the new system on your site.  Then you have new functionality set up, and you didn't have to touch any code!

#### Syntax Highlighting

I use a syntax highlighter on my own site for displaying PHP and JavaScript code.  It's called [Code Colorer](http://kpumuk.info/projects/wordpress-plugins/codecolorer/), and it supports a wide variety of languages and structures - you can even use a custom theme to color/style your code snippets if you want.  Here's an example on my site [using PHP](http://mindsharestrategy.com/google-reader-api-a-brief-tutorial/).  Here's an example [using JavaScript](http://mindsharestrategy.com/javascript-event-bus/).

#### Other Resources

Here are some other places you can look for more information regarding getting a WordPress blog set up on your own system:

- [WordPress Web Hosting](http://wordpress.org/hosting/)
- [WordPress Hosting with GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/wordpress-hosting.aspx)
- [How to Setup a Self-hosted WordPress Blog For Free](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-build-a-self-hosted-wordpress-blog-for-free/)
- [Jumping Duck Media Web Hosting](http://jumping-duck.com/about-us/web-development/) *(Full Disclosure: This is my company!)*